# Apple keeps marking my app as Developer Rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm having this weird issue with the AppStore review right now where Apple keeps marking my app as "Developer Rejected."

I originally marked the build as Developer Rejected, but then I tried submitting a new build but it keeps getting marked as Developer Rejected.

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's an easy way to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my organization was silently and automatically marking the build as Developer Rejected because of us not following their process.
Somehow it appeared as if Apple had marked it.